# React native get internet quality, bad normal or good

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to show theese wifi icons to user to show  internet speed. **None, low or Good**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I installed

`"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",` but didn't do what i want

then i installed an old package `"react-native-network-speed": "^1.1.2",`

It console logs like this

```
downLoadSpeed 24kb/s
downLoadSpeedCurrent 22kb/s
56kb/s
57kb/s
downLoadSpeed 21kb/s
downLoadSpeedCurrent 19kb/s
70kb/s
65kb/s
downLoadSpeed 19kb/s
downLoadSpeedCurrent 16kb/s
```

How can i do this. Thank you. I really need this.

Comment: npm install then link thats what i did. It gives download speed as mentioned in bottom

Comment: Ok, where are you trying to display these icons? Do you have example of the code you're using on the screen or component where you'd like to display these icons? Which metrics are you using to determine which speed ranges map to the icon to display?

Comment: Well simply showing theese icon by state management. THe metrics are idk exactlye which is slow which is good.However it gaves download speed in kb/s.

Comment: You have to match the download speed with your icons yourself, you will have to do some research based on where your end-users live and what common download speeds are.

Comment: i  think speed is common, i cant make a search its pretty big.Just gotta show icons :)

Comment: Well anyone done this before ?

Comment: I'm still need this

Answer (score 0):

You need to set boundary value in kb/s which separates "bad" and "good" connections depending on your needs (every value below the boundary value is bad). The test must be done, using tools for controlling connection speed on your device, with your backend services so you can determine the boundary value.

For the "none" state you can use mentioned library "@react-native-community/netinfo", where you can listen to connection changes and act upon that.